# Clustering words based on Distance Matrix

Tags: python, cluster-computing, scikit-learn, hierarchical-clustering

My objective is to cluster words based on how similar they are with respect to a corpus of text documents. I have computed Jaccard Similarity between every pair of words. In other words, I have a sparse distance matrix available with me. Can anyone point me to any clustering algorithm (and possibly its library in Python) which takes distance matrix as input ? I also do not know the number of clusters beforehand. I only want to cluster these words and obtain which words are clustered together.

Comment: take a look at http://code.google.com/p/em-python/ and "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation–maximization_algorithm"

Comment: there is also http://www.pymix.org/pymix/index.php?n=PyMix.Tutorial

Comment: @Moj I'm sorry...I can't seem to figure out how the information contained in the links you have mentioned are relevant here

Comment: (EM) algorithm is an iterative method for finding maximum likelihood or maximum a posteriori (MAP) estimates of parameters in statistical models, where the model depends on unobserved latent variables. The EM iteration alternates between performing an expectation (E) step, which creates a function for the expectation of the log-likelihood evaluated using the current estimate for the. I guess this fit you goal as also don't know the number of clusters before hand. those are two libraries(or implementation ) of this algorithm .

Comment: @Moj I was hoping something along the lines of k-means or hierarchical clustering...i know these require the number of clusters to be known beforehand.....but i hope there are ways to figure out the optimum number of clusters

Answer (score 15):

You can use most algorithms in scikit-learn with a precomputed distance matrix. Unfortunately you need the number of clusters for many algorithm.
[DBSCAN](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/clustering.html#dbscan) is the only one that doesn't need the number of clusters and also uses arbitrary distance matrices.
You could also try [MeanShift](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/clustering.html#mean-shift), but that will interpret the distances as coordinates - which might also work.

There is also [affinity propagation](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/clustering.html#affinity-propagation), but I haven't really seen that working well. If you want many clusters, that might be helpful, though.

disclosure: I'm a scikit-learn core dev.

Comment: can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of a scikit-learn algorithm using a distance matrix as input?

Comment: There is one here: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/cluster/plot_segmentation_toy.html

Comment: Is there somewhere a list of algorithms in sklearn that can take precomputed distance matrix? I found, for example that while DBSCAN does accept it, a very similar algorithm, OPTICS does not. In AgglomerativeClustering 'ward' linkage does not, while other linkages do.

Answer (score 10):

The scipy clustering package could be usefull ([scipy.cluster](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/cluster.html)). There are hierarchical clustering functions in [scipy.cluster.hierarchy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/cluster.hierarchy.html#module-scipy.cluster.hierarchy). Note however that those require a condensed matrix as input (the upper triangular of the distance matrix). Hopefully the documentation pages will help you along.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend to take a look at agglomerative clustering.